# How to automatically run a python script when Google Cloud Compute Instance starts

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I would like to have gcp turn on my instance in the morning and run a python script all day without me using ssh.
I have added the startup-script metadata to the instance I have also added a cronjob to the Linux side but none of it works so please could someone help me.
p.s I'm new to Linux and GCP

[my shell script]

```
#!/bin/bash
cd '/home/issaca/main/'
nohup python3 main.py &
```

Comment: WHy a VM? What about a server less product?

Comment: it receives forex prices and calculates indicators. I'm new to the cloud so I chose the most common option of a VM. please could you explain if serverless is better in this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- have a script stored on the vm

`sudo cat /root/main.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from time import sleep
while True:
    sleep(5)
```

- metadata startup-script to run your script on startup:

```
#!/bin/bash
/root/main.py
```

- [Instance scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/schedule-instance-start-stop) to start and stop your machine at the time of your choosing

Then if you can check whether your script is running with

```
sudo ps aux | grep [m]ain
```

or

```
pgrep -a -u root python3
```

if your script is not running, check the logs with `sudo journalctl -u google-startup-scripts.service` or in the `/var/log/[messages,syslog,daemon].log` files.

Comment: with the startup-script will it run without ssh terminal or do I have to use something like nohup

Comment: does your script need ssh terminal for some reason? if not it should be fine. example above works without any nohups

Comment: no, I just need it to run all day. but suppose I open ssh to make some changes or to check up on it I still need it to work in the background without closing even when I quit ssh

Comment: Let me know if it doesn't work for you, we will think of something else

Comment: yes, it works I just had to also use nohup and & and also had to move it out of root into 
 \main\main.py as there were some directory errors in python but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This feature did not use to exist. It seems it just came out. Please have a look at this doc on how to [schedule to start your instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/schedule-instance-start-stop#console). It is implemented within the compute engine UI.

Previously, one had to go through [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/save-money-by-stopping-and-starting-compute-engine-instances-on-schedule).